# Can you send information with gravity?

Tags: gravity, soft-question

Admittedly, I dont know a whole lot about the gravitational wave discovery, but could it theoretically be used to send information ridiculous distances?

The G-waves could carry data in a similar manner as EM waves.  The generation of the G-wave might be problematic, as will its detection.
What about the speed of said transfer?  As far as I understand, gravity "travels" the speed of light

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, you could send information via gravitational waves. But there's a lot of practical issues with it. Gravity is weak, so it would take a lot more effort to transmit and receive gravitational waves than electromagnetic ones. Gravitational waves also travel at the speed of light (the "speed limit" of the universe) so it's not like you'd get any practical benefits over EM waves in that department. I don't really see any benefits of using gravitational waves over EM waves to transmit information over large distances at this point in time. It would be kind of like using neutrinos to send information...theoretically possible, but practically intractable - at least currently.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Another question:   Would Gwaves decay at a slower rate than EM waves?

Comment: No, not really. Gravitational waves from "far away" (where we can use perturbation theory to describe them) decay just like EM waves. I guess if you were close by to the gravitational wave source, it's possible that the gravitation distorts space time in such a way that its decay would be different than for EM waves. But as long as you are "far away" where the distortion to space time is small then gravity waves will decay the same as EM waves.

Comment: An advantage over EM waves would be that gravitational waves don't get absorbed by the interstellar medium. There might also be an advantage in terms of signal/noise.

Comment: I would have thought that simply using infrared would be a far superior choice at this time if absorption by the interstellar medium is an issue...? I'm not an expert in observational astronomy however, so I'm not sure. AFAIK there are no known efforts to implement communication by gravity waves, but I'd love to see a source for it if it exists, that would actually be super cool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! But Einsteins gravitational waves are not easy to produce and to detect. If you dearly need to send information by waves related to gravitation, it would be far easier to use another type of wave, [water gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave).